# Can not find my app in the store (Windows Phone app store)

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-store

I updated my Windows Phone 8 app and selected "show app in store" it was hidden for 5 days. 12 hours have passed and my app is still not
visible if searched by keywords or app name. However I can reach my app by clicking on the app link which is shown on my dashboard. Do I have to wait 
a little bit longer or is there another problem? I must say that all my other apps are visible by searching by keyword or their name.

Comment: I'm just guessing here because I'm not familiar with the app store. But perhaps there's a flag somewhere that says "don't advertise" or "keep hidden" or something similar. Perhaps you should look for that. Or maybe it's set for [Targeted App Distribution](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj619160(v=vs.105).aspx).

Comment: I checked completely everything and everything seems fine. I think that I ll have to wait a little bit more to see if it will be shown to users or not...

Comment: Of course yeah, you have to wait a little bit more, because same thing happened to me where it took around 2 weeks. It depends on the app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to wait 2 days to get things sorted. For everyone else experiencing the same problem, You have to wait.